# Linux Fedora virtualenv site-packages incorrect location

Tags: python, linux, virtualenv, fedora

I have just tried to set install an application in my new virtual environment.

To create my virtual environment I used:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.6/python2.6 rollEnv2 --no-site-packages
```

Then to install the application, I used:

```
python setup.py install
```

But I get an error at the end:

```
File "/home/aaron/workspace/rollEnv2/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/setuptools/package_index.py", line 475, in fetch_distribution
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clone'
```

Well lets try to serve the application anyway:

```
paster serve development.ini
```

Error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 588, in resolve
raise VersionConflict(dist,req) # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (WebOb 1.0.8 (/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('WebOb==0.9.6.1'))
(rollEnv2)
```

Seems like an obvious error, lets just:

```
easy_install WebOb==0.9.6.1
```

But:

```
WebOb 0.9.6.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
```

So what could be the problem here? It is as if easy install is looking in the base Python directory instead of the virtualenv directory. But ideally it would be nice to fix the original `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clone'`.

I've googled around, but I just cant seem to find a decent answer to this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would advise you to try out [mkvirtualenv](http://www.doughellmann.com/articles/pythonmagazine/completely-different/2008-05-virtualenvwrapper/index.html) also, why are you still using easy_install and haven't switched to pip ?

By default virtualenv uses Distribute not setuptools. I think you are using setuptools, so just recreate your environment with setuptools.

From the virtualenv:

```
--distribute          Ignored.  Distribute is used by default. See
                      --setuptools to use Setuptools instead of Distribute.
```

Comment: Brilliant, pip install worked. I wasnt aware it was possible to install applications using pip, I considered it to be more like yum. Thanks.